# Twitter exception4 04:The URI requested is invalid

Tags: android, twitter4j

I want to send direct message to user's followers using my android application.I have tried following code

```
      String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(
                        Constants.PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
                // Access Token Secret
                String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(
                        Constants.PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setDebugEnabled(true);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
                builder.setOAuthAccessToken(access_token);
                builder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(access_token_secret);


                TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(builder.build());
                Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();


                DirectMessage message = null;
                try {
                    message = twitter.sendDirectMessage(
                            frndsDetails.get(position).getId(), "Hi");
                    System.out.println("Sent: " + message.getText()
                            + " to @" + message.getRecipientScreenName());

                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.e("Twitter exception", "" + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

But got following exception

> 02-26 13:48:16.287: E/Twitter exception(707): 404:The URI requested
>   is invalid or the resource requested, such as a user, does not exists.
>   Also returned when the requested format is not supported by the
>   requested method. 02-26 13:48:16.287: E/Twitter exception(707):
>   message - Sorry, that page does not exist 02-26 13:48:16.287:
>   E/Twitter exception(707): code - 34 02-26 13:48:16.397:
>   W/System.err(707):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)

Is there any other method for sending direct message.Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once check access level of your application in twitter developer site. We need to set AccessLevel to 'Read, write, and direct messages' for send direct messages.

Comment: Access level is set to Read,write and direct messages

Comment: Please provide me some help...

Answer (score 1):

I have used following code in my application for sending direct messages to the followers. May be this can helpful to you.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("@").append(twitterFriendObj.screenName).append(" ");
Status status = twitter.updateStatus(builder+"Hi this is test message");
```

Here we need to send follower screen name to send direct message.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I have used screenname instead of id and the twitter.sendDirectMessage worked for me.